# Using C++ RTTI (introspection) to lookup function pointers by string?

Tags: c++, rtti

I wonder if it's possible to use RTTI in order get a static method/ function pointer using its name (passed as string)

So far i have the following code:

```cpp
#include <map>

int Foo() {
  return 42;
}

int Bar() {
  return 117;
}

typedef int (*function_ptr)();

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, function_ptr> fctmap;
  fctmap["Foo"] = Foo;
  fctmap["Bar"] = Bar;
}
```

This method of setting and keeping a manual mapping of functions pointers is, as far as i'm concerned, highly inelegant. Is there an "automatic" way ?

Comment: RTTI is not introspection. There's simply no standard way to map a string to a variable unless you explicitly implement such a mapping.

Comment: Even if RTTI had an opposite mapping, a type is not the same kind of thing as a function. Both `Foo` and `Bar` are things of type `int()` (which are implicitly convertible to `int(*)()`)

Comment: To prevent typos, you could use a macro (ignoring all concerns about macros in C++): `#define REGISTER(FUNC) fctmap[#FUNC] = FUNC`, use it `REGISTER(Foo); REGISTER(Bar);`, and (if paranoid like me) undefine it again `#undef REGISTER`. Unfortunately, I know no other reliable technique in C++ which provides something comparable like the [macro stringize](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html).

Comment: Have you considered using a different language?  Looking up functions by name, at runtime, with all the overhead that brings, is more typical of an interpreted language like Ruby than a compiled language like C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you be open to use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`? If so, you can get the name of the function by parsing the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` string.

Then, you can have a helper function that inserts the function pointers in the map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using Map = std::map<std::string, int(*)()>;

//-------------------------------------//

template<int(*)()>
struct Get
{
    static constexpr std::string name()
    {
        std::string tmp = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
        auto s = tmp.find("= ");
        auto e = tmp.find("; ");
        return std::string(tmp.substr(s+2, e-s-2));
    }
};

template<int(*func)()>
void insert2map(Map &fctmap_)
{
    fctmap_[Get<func>::name()] = func;
}

//-------------------------------------//

int Foo()
{
    return 42;
}

int Bar()
{
    return 117;
}

int VeryVeryLongName()
{
    return 101;
}

//-------------------------------------//

int main()
{
    Map fctmap;

    insert2map<Foo>(fctmap);
    insert2map<Bar>(fctmap);
    insert2map<VeryVeryLongName>(fctmap);

    for (auto &&i : fctmap)
        std::cout<< i.first <<" -> "<<i.second() <<std::endl;
}
```

It seems to work well in this case. The results are:

```
Bar -> 117
Foo -> 42
VeryVeryLongName -> 101
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/OHZK79342

Comment: Hi @Constantinos, this is a quite conveniant solution therefore i accept it :) The only drawback is that __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ is not entirely portable, but i could get over it with a series of #ifdef __compiler__ directives.

Comment: @WintermeW: No problem - glad it helps out. Yer, you definitely need to do some tweaking if you want the code to be portable... Btw, one of the comments above, mentioned macros. Regardless of what's been considered about macros, they can be quite handy at times and in this case, I believe they would do the job just fine. Just food for thought. :-)